# What is this rather large insect in northwestern USA?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

As you can see from the ants in the first picture, this insect is peculiarly large - over an inch long. I thought it was dead in the first picture, but it started moving around the next day. A couple of days later I found it again, dead. I have two dead specimens and other pictures if desired.

[image]

[image]

I think I've seen a shedded exoskeleton of one on a forest trail and another dead one from months earlier.

What species is it?

Location: Oregon, USA.

Comment: I just edited your question's title, changing the state for the country.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Jerusalem cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_cricket), an insect from the Genus *Stenopelmatus*.

Here is an image of *Stenopelmatus fuscus* for comparison:

[image]

Comment: PS: I was almost sure that this was a duplicate, I remember seeing this insect before on Bio SE. However, I searched *"Jerusalem"* and *"Stenopelmatus"* and found nothing.

Comment: Stopping at genus here is the best course; I misremember where I read this, but the genus _Stenopelmatus_ is known to have upwards of fifty species that have not yet been named, with the more widely distributed species (of which _fuscus_ is one) recognized as composite (there's more than one species hiding in the published records of that name).

Comment: @ArthurJFrost In reading articles on "Jerusalem cricket", I saw it was mentioned in a few that there were quite a few similar species not entirely documented or studied yet.